# Cannot install vinkla/pusher in laravel

Tags: laravel, pusher

I am trying to integrate Pusher with Laravel application. When I try to install Pusher Bridge vinkla/pusher I am getting below error

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for vinkla/pusher ^2.3 -> satisfiable by vinkla/pusher[2.3.0].
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.0.35
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.35
    - vinkla/pusher 2.3.0 requires illuminate/contracts 5.1.* || 5.2.* || 5.3.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/contracts[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.6, v5.2.7].
    - don't install illuminate/contracts v5.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.35
    - don't install illuminate/contracts v5.1.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.35
    - don't install illuminate/contracts v5.1.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.35
    - don't install illuminate/contracts v5.1.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.35
    - don't install illuminate/contracts v5.1.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.35
    - don't install illuminate/contracts v5.1.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.35
    - don't install illuminate/contracts v5.1.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.35
    - don't install illuminate/contracts v5.1.30|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.35
    - don't install illuminate/contracts v5.1.31|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.35
    - don't install illuminate/contracts v5.1.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.35
    - don't install illuminate/contracts v5.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.35
    - don't install illuminate/contracts v5.2.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.35
    - don't install illuminate/contracts v5.2.21|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.35
    - don't install illuminate/contracts v5.2.24|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.35
    - don't install illuminate/contracts v5.2.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.35
    - don't install illuminate/contracts v5.2.26|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.35
    - don't install illuminate/contracts v5.2.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.35
    - don't install illuminate/contracts v5.2.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.35
    - don't install illuminate/contracts v5.2.31|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.35
    - don't install illuminate/contracts v5.2.32|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.35
    - don't install illuminate/contracts v5.2.37|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.35
    - don't install illuminate/contracts v5.2.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.35
    - don't install illuminate/contracts v5.2.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.35
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.0.35, required as 5.0.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.0.35].
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of *vinkla/pusher* 2.3.0 requires *illuminate* packages with version 5.1.x, but it seems your versions are 5.0.x, so you should be ok installing version 2.1.0 which is ok with 5.0.x:

`composer require vinkla/pusher:2.1.0`